# How to update my database on stripe checkout.session.completed

Tags: php

```
//non working code from stripe documentation

require_once "config.php";

// Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production!
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('EXAMPLE_KEY');


// You can find your endpoint's secret in your webhook settings
$endpoint_secret = 'EXAMPLE_SECRET';

$payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$sig_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'];
$event = null;

try {
    $event = \Stripe\Webhook::constructEvent(
        $payload, $sig_header, $endpoint_secret
    );
} catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
    // Invalid payload
    http_response_code(400);
    exit();
} catch(\Stripe\Exception\SignatureVerificationException $e) {
    // Invalid signature
    http_response_code(400);
    exit();
}

function fulfill_order($session) {
    // TODO: fill me in
    $order_id = $session->client_reference_id;

}

function create_order($session) {
    // TODO fill me in
}

function email_customer_about_failed_payment($session) {
    // TODO fill me in
}

switch ($event->type) {
    case 'checkout.session.completed':
        $session = $event->data->object;

        $data = $database->update("orders", [
            "payment_status" => 1
        ], [
            "id" => 64
        ]);

        if($data){
            echo 'success';
        }

        // Save an order in your database, marked as 'awaiting payment'
        create_order($session);

        // Check if the order is paid (e.g., from a card payment)
        //
        // A delayed notification payment will have an `unpaid` status, as
        // you're still waiting for funds to be transferred from the customer's
        // account.
        if ($session->payment_status == 'paid') {
            // Fulfill the purchase
            fulfill_order($session);
        }

        break;

    case 'checkout.session.async_payment_succeeded':
        $session = $event->data->object;

        // Fulfill the purchase
        fulfill_order($session);

        break;

    case 'checkout.session.async_payment_failed':
        $session = $event->data->object;

        // Send an email to the customer asking them to retry their order
        email_customer_about_failed_payment($session);

        break;
}

http_response_code(200);

?>
```

```html
<?php
//working code from github

/*******************************************************************************
 *
 * Created 12/16/14 - contact John at pellmllism@gmail.com
 * Check for updates at https://github.com/Pellmellism/PHP-Stripe-Webhook-Script
 *
 * INSTRUCTIONS
 * Host this page and take note of the URL
 * Log into Stripe.com and build a webhook for this new URL
 * Edit this file for each of the Stripe events you want to acknowledge
 * Some example uses are at the bottom of this document
 *
 * *****************************************************************************/

require_once "_includes/config.php";

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_51HjoRfIaBaXJG6ud5YpkWXn8uS5d6JLO4SWIa0pYfyNx9f8afcK3hYmnKx0Rcu5F446huOqmFxm2RaIDDViugybE00nkegCBQx');

// This function is leveraged to search through the JSON for specific values
function searchArrayValueByKey(array $array, $search) {
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array)) as $key => $value) {
        if ($search === $key)
            return $value;
    }
    return false;
}

global $type;

$input = @file_get_contents("php://input");         // this gets the POST data provided when the webhook pings this page

$event_json = json_decode($input, TRUE);            // decode the JSON, and TRUE turns it into a multidimensional array

if($event_json){
    $type = searchArrayValueByKey($event_json, 'type'); // Check the type of event sent from Stripe.com - example "charge.succeeded"
    $id = searchArrayValueByKey($event_json, 'client_reference_id');
}else{
    echo 'No event recieved';
}


switch ($type) {                                 // depending on the event fired by Stripe, do something different.
    case "checkout.session.completed":
        $data = $database->update("orders", [
            "payment_status" => 1
        ], [
            "id" => $id
        ]);
        break;
    case "balance.available":
        // do something
        break;
    case "charge.captured":
        // do something
        break;
    case "charge.refunded":
        // do something
        break;
    case "charge.succeeded":
        // do something
        break;
    case "charge.updated":
        // do something
        break;
    case "charge.failed":
        // do something
        break;
    case "charge.dispute.created":
        // do something
        break;
    case "charge.dispute.updated":
        // do something
        break;
    case "charge.dispute.closed":
        // do something
        break;
    case "coupon.created":
        // do something
        break;
    case "coupon.deleted":
        // do something
        break;
    case "customer.created":
        // do something
        break;
    case "customer.updated":
        // do something
        break;
    case "customer.deleted":
        // do something
        break;
    case "customer.card.created":
        // do something
        break;
    case "customer.card.updated":
        // do something
        break;
    case "customer.card.deleted":
        // do something
        break;
    case "customer.discount.created":
        // do something
        break;
    case "customer.discount.updated":
        // do something
        break;
    case "customer.discount.deleted":
        // do something
        break;
    case "customer.subscription.created":
        // do something
        break;
    case "customer.subscription.updated":
        // do something
        break;
    case "customer.subscription.deleted":
        // do something
        break;
    case "customer.subscription.trial_will_end":
        // do something
        break;
    case "invoice.created":
        // do something
        break;
    case "invoice.updated":
        // do something
        break;
    case "invoice.payment_succeeded":
        // do something
        break;
    case "invoice.payment_failed":
        // do something
        break;
    case "invoiceitem.created":
        // do something
        break;
    case "invoiceitem.updated":
        // do something
        break;
    case "invoiceitem.deleted":
        // do something
        break;
    case "plan.created":
        // do something
        break;
    case "plan.updated":
        // do something
        break;
    case "plan.deleted":
        // do something
        break;
    case "transfer.created":
        // do something
        break;
    case "transfer.updated":
        // do something
        break;
    case "transfer.paid":
        // do something
        break;
    case "transfer.failed":
        // do something
        break;
    default:
        // An error has occured, this was not a Stripe.com event - log into your Stripe.com account and check the log.

}

/*
DETAILED DESCRIPTION IN RELATIVELY PLAIN ENGLISH
Stripe webhooks allow you to know how about the status of a transaction. If you have a customer purchase a
widget, you might consider recording that customers email and customerID in a database at the time of purchase
then use a webhooh to record how that transaction had proceeded. For example, waiting until a card is successfully
charged before emailing a customer a downloadable file.
The webhook is a URL that Stripe sends information about the transaction to along the way, so for each event of the transaction
you will recieve a detailed descripton as it happens. For example, as a customer subscribes to a service there are various stages -
First, the customer.created event occurs, followed by charge.succeeded, invoice.created, invroice.payment_succeeded, customer.card.created, and
finally customer.subscription.created. You may decide that during one of those events that the customer should get an email, or that
a database should be updated to reflect new information.
The information that Stripe sends to the webhook is formatted in JSON and we use PHP to decode the data and then search the data for
specific information we can use to identify the transaction and details about how the transaction occured. The data will have different
information in it depending on which event occured, but there are some standard peices of information that are always included. If you
head over to your stripe dashboard, you can test the webhooks and in the test sessions you can learn what informtion is sent with each event.
You can search the data by the descriptor, or the key value by running it through the searchArrayValueByKey() function.
A sample of the JSON data might look like this -->
                        {
                          "created": 1326853468,
                          "livemode": false,
                          "id": "evt_00000000000000",
                          "type": "charge.succeeded",
                          "object": "event",
                          "request": null,
                          "pending_webhooks": 1,
                          "api_version": "2014-12-08",
                          "data": {
                            "object": {
                              "id": "ch_00000000000000",
                              "object": "charge",
                              "created": 1418689534,
                              "livemode": false,
                              "paid": true,
                              "amount": 100,
                              "currency": "usd",
                              "refunded": false,
                              "captured": true,
                              "card": {
                                "id": "card_00000000000000",
                                "object": "card",
                                "last4": "4242",
                                "brand": "Visa",
                                "funding": "credit",
                                "exp_month": 2,
                                "exp_year": 2022,
                                "fingerprint": "qj49tV3y7axAqjD3",
                                "country": "US",
                                "name": "demo@gmail.com",
                                "address_line1": null,
                                "address_line2": null,
                                "address_city": null,
                                "address_state": null,
                                "address_zip": null,
                                "address_country": null,
                                "cvc_check": "pass",
                                "address_line1_check": null,
                                "address_zip_check": null,
                                "dynamic_last4": null,
                                "customer": "cus_00000000000000"
                              },
                              "balance_transaction": "txn_00000000000000",
                              "failure_message": null,
                              "failure_code": null,
                              "amount_refunded": 0,
                              "customer": "cus_00000000000000",
                              "invoice": "in_00000000000000",
                              "description": null,
                              "dispute": null,
                              "metadata": {},
                              "statement_description": "test",
                              "fraud_details": {},
                              "receipt_email": "payinguser@example.com",
                              "receipt_number": null,
                              "shipping": null,
                              "refunds": {
                                "object": "list",
                                "total_count": 0,
                                "has_more": false,
                                "url": "/v1/charges/ch_15A96QL8CfRmpdofR6emWQyW/refunds",
                                "data": []
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
Every use case will be different, but the nature of a webhook is to
    1 - detect a specific event
    2 - check who triggered the event
    3 - do something.

We can easily identify the event, Stripe ensures each webhook is sent with the event type defined.
Depending on the event and the use case, we will want more information from that event.
*/



//Some examples of actions you might take when Stripe fires an event can be found below.
//Copy and past the code into the "//do something" sections for the event your interested in
//#################################################################################################
/*
EXAMPLE - SEND AN EMAIL

    //get some of the customers details from the webhook
    $customerID    = searchArrayValueByKey($event_json, 'customer');
    $customerName  = searchArrayValueByKey($event_json, 'name');
    $customerEmail = searchArrayValueByKey($event_json, 'receipt_email');
    //constuct the email
    $youremail= 'test@test.com';    // set your email address
    $subject  = 'Test webhooks';    // set the subject
    $headers  = "From: " . strip_tags($customerName) . "<" . strip_tags($customerEmail) . ">\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($customerEmail) . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $message = 'The customer with ID "'.$customerID.'" just bought a really expensive widget';
    // actually send the email
    @mail($youremail, $subject, $message, $headers);

*/
//#################################################################################################
/*
EXAMPLE - UPDATE A MYSQL DATABASE

    //get some of the customers details from the webhook
    $customerID    = searchArrayValueByKey($event_json, 'customer');
    $customerName  = searchArrayValueByKey($event_json, 'name');
    $customerEmail = searchArrayValueByKey($event_json, 'receipt_email');

    // your MySQL database credentials
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);     // connect to your database
    $sql = "UPDATE MyGuests SET lastname='Doe' WHERE id=2";                 // build the query
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);                                              // actually tap the database
    mysqli_close($conn);                                                    // close the connection

*/
//#################################################################################################
/*
EXAMPLE - SEND A TEXT MESSAGE WITH TWILIO.COM

    //in this example, we will have twilio send a text message to our phone whenever someone buys something
    //include the Twilio library, get it at https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/archive/master.zip
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/twilio-php-master/Services/Twilio.php');
    $twilioAccountSID = 'YOUR-TWILIO-ACCOUNT-SID-HERE';
    $twilioAuthKey    = 'YOUR-TWILIO-AUTH-KEY-HERE';
    $MyTwilioNumber   = '15557773333'; //this is your twilio SMS capable phone number
    $CellPhoneNumber  = '15553337777'; //this is your personal cell phone that you want to get the message
    $customer = searchArrayValueByKey($event_json, 'customer'); //get the customers identifier who made the purchase
    $message  = 'The customer "'.$customer.'"just ordered an expensive widget'; // build the body of the text message

    //actually send the message by calling the twilio library
    $client = new Services_Twilio($twilioAccountSID, $twilioAuthKey);
    $sms = $client->account->sms_messages->create(
        "$MyTwilioNumber",      // From this number
        "$CellPhoneNumber",     // To this number
        "$message"              // with this message
        );
    // the message is sent, check your phone

*/
//#################################################################################################






//  GETTING WEBHOOK ERRORS??

//Depending on your hosting environment, you may want to serve an HTTP response code for Stripe.com
//If your webhooks fail for stripe, they may repeat until successful, but failure may occur if
//an HTTP 200 isnt recieved by Stripe when they trigger the webhook. You may try ending this
//script by uncomenting line below (remove the 2 slashes before the http_response_code(200);)

//http_response_code(200);

?>
```

I 'am currently coding my first E-Shop with stripe. I have a form that that user fills with shipping info and the checkout button. On the checkout button click the form is submit to database and assigned unique order ID and defual payment_status = false. Then user is redirected to stripe prebuild checkout page.

After successful payment I want to receive webhook from stripe and If the payment succeeded update the payment_status = true in my database for the CERTAIN USER (order_id) that has done the payment.

I have multiple problems:

1. How do I know the ID of the order?...is there any way to pass it along with email to checkout.session and then receive it with event in my webhook endpoint?
2. I have tried sample code (provided by stripe) to make update to database on checkout.session.completed...however this code wont work :(...So I have found another code in the internet that works for me...but I DONT THINK it is still save in 2020 to use this code because it does not verify if the webhook was sent by stripe ://

Any suggestions on how to make it work?

Comment: Please only post code that is relevant so that readers dont need to read everything. Eg comments can be stripped, unneeded functions, 35 case statements is 30 more than needed for an example, etc

Comment: Is that your real API key? You might think about changing it now...

Comment: No it is not the real production API key...Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across the same problem. I did it by creating checkoutSession column in my Orders table. I pass my order id through the createCheckoutSession method and after creating the checkout session and send it back as a response to Stripe, I set my order's checkoutSession id. After successful checkout, stripe sends back response to your webhook, you can get the checkout session there and compare it to the checkoutSession in your order and update it. Here's my code in Symfony Framework:

**Template with payment button:**

```
fetch('{{ path('create_checkout_session', { orderId: order.id }) }}', {
   method: 'POST',
}) // This function creates the checkout session on my backend and passes the order id as parameter
```

**Create checkout session and send it to stripe:**

```
try {
    $session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
                    'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
                    'line_items' => $lineItems,
                    'mode' => 'payment',
                    'success_url' => $domain . $this->generateUrl('checkout_success'),
                    'cancel_url' => $domain . $this->generateUrl('cart_list'),
                ]);

                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $order = $em->getRepository('App:Order\Order')->findOneBy(['id' => $orderId]);
                $order->setCheckoutSession($session->id);
                $em->persist($order);
                $em->flush();
                // I save the checkout session id in my order entity here
            }
```

**Webhook that receives stripe response:**

```
switch ($event->type) {                                                                                    
    case 'checkout.session.completed':                                                                     
        $session = $event->data->object;    
                                                                                                                          
    if ($session->payment_status == 'paid') {                                                          
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();                                                      
        $order = $em->getRepository('App:Order\Order')->findOneBy(['checkoutSession' => $session->id]);
        $order->setPaymentStatus($session->payment_status);                                            
        $em->persist($order);                                                                          
        $em->flush();                                                                                  
    }                                                                                                  
                                                                                                       
    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create a stripe check out session you can pass a field called **client_reference_id** ..Since you are creating the order before creating stripe session you can pass order id using this field and receive it on **checkout.session.completed** event..
Additionally stripe provides metadata field to store additional info as key value pairs..